# canvas.toDataURL() returns 'is not a function'

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to convert an HTMLCanvasElement into an image:

```
window.open(document.querySelector("canvas.page").toDataURL())
```

returns: `Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...).toDataURL is not a function`

up until
`document.querySelector("canvas.page")`
it gives me the right canvas but then the `toDataURL()` fails somehow.

pls help

Comment: can you show us some more of your code? since it is impossible to reproduce the issue
`document.createElement('canvas').toDataURL()` works

Comment: Im on a website and execute that in the console: window.open(document.querySelector("canvas.page").toDataURL()) so the canvas is already there and i can get it with querySelector

Comment: So put it at the end of the file instead of the header

Comment: i just execute it in console

Comment: the object you are looking for is either not a canvas or never found to begin with, please double check your css selectors